# If file_exists Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm new coding and Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

I want to see if a image exists in a folder but it won't display the image if it exists.

```
{assign var="backimg" value="/thumbs/backgrounds/movie_bg/`$mov.title|lower|replace:' ':'_'`.jpg"}
{ if file_exists($backimg) }
<div class="container_inner"
style="background:url(/thumbs/backgrounds/movie_bg/{$mov.title|lower|replace:' ':'_'}.jpg)no-repeat center;">
{else}
<div class="container_inner">
{/if}
```

Could someone tell me if there is anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Does relevant html code appear in the source? It can have different path when accessed from web than to one accessed from filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty is a templating language. You don't write PHP code into a template like that. You do the logic in the PHP code that calls the template, assigning whatever values are needed to render the page correctly to the template, and then render the template.

```
// In the PHP code.
// (Simplified. The actual code to initialize Smarty will usually be more complex.)
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign("file_exists", file_exists('/file/path'));
$smarty->display('mytemplate.tpl');

// In the 'mytemplate.tpl' template file.
{if $file_exists}
    <p>File exist!</p>
{else}
    <p>File doesn't exist</p>
{/if}
```